# Typo3 no module found with new user

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using Typo3 6.2 and I have added a user account (backend user). When I now login with this new user I get the error message "no module found". When I login again with my admin account everything is fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have probably created an unprivileged user (editor). You need to give this user explicitly access to backend modules, pages, tables, folders in the file list, and so on. To do that, one usually creates a backend user group (either in the "edit user" screen, or as a record on the root page), sets the permissions for this group, and assigns it to the user.

Comment: @Jost please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably created an unprivileged user (editor). You need to explicitely give users access to

- Backend modules
- Subtrees of the page tree
- Folders
- Tables

and so on.

To do that, you usually create a backend user group, set the permissions for this group, and assign it to the user.

You can create the group either on the root page (id 0) as record or in the user management module, where you assign the groups to users.

There are two functionalities two make pages visible for users/groups:

1. You need to add the root of the subtree a groups should be able to use to the group as a mount point.
2. You need to give the group the right to view/edit/delete/update the pages. You can do that as admin in the "Access"-module. It's similar to the Unix owner/group concept.

Comment: Thanks now the page modules are loaded. Only I cannot see any pages or the root domain. I did link all pages to the new user group under my admin account, but when the user login is there are no pages?

Comment: I've edited the question with more information, please check that. Also check that your users are allowed to view and modify the `pages` table.